# How to fix "ModuleNotFoundError" on PyCharm Mac OS

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm and just downloaded it and I've never used it before.

So, I've just make some code for basic learning from YouTube and it make me frustrate because the program always say these one

```
/Users/erzajullian/PycharmProjects/Checker/venv/bin/python /Users/erzajullian/PycharmProjects/Checker/checker.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/erzajullian/PycharmProjects/Checker/checker.py", line 1, in <module>
    import request
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'request'
```

[image: Screenshot]

I've already tried to install pip on terminal (inside PyCharm) but still getting these code.

Can anyone who using PyCharm on Mac maybe you can fixed this problem? Is it very basic I know, it not about the code, but about the program.

Comment: What is `request`? Is it like `requests`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the Pycharm interpreter is the same where you use pip from.
So if the PyCharm is pointing to /users/joe/x/y/python3.7 make sure you pip3.7 points there too